# Simple question about "this" statement in C#

Tags: c#, this

```
class first
{
    internal string log = "";

    public bool something(second obj)
    {
        if (obj.check(this) == true)
          return true;          
        else
            return false;
    }
}

class second
{
    public bool check(first obj)
    {
        if (obj.log == "yes")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So in this code that you see above there is a statement `obj.check(this)`, what I'm wondering is what that `this` is referring to? I just started programming and my professor didn't really get into it.

Comment: Are you asking what [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) is or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you are working with objects which are instances of a specific class.
You might consider class as a blueprint of something. For example a blueprint how to build a car, but it's not a car. An object is an instance of that blueprint, so for example each car is an object of class `Car`.

When you use `this` you refer to object you are currently using. For example, when you are with your friend in a lobby and you are asked who is registering for an event. You could reply `me` and everyone know who is registering. In this case `me` is `this` and tells to whom it refers.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the "current" object the method is being called on.

Comment: That's what I assumed but is there any other way to refer to the current object than writing  `this`, I've tried putting "first" as a class instead of  `this` but that's not it.

Comment: @EmeraldCube, in question you say you just wondering, but from your comment it seems you are trying to do something. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sinatr, yea I was wondering what the keyword `this` stands for and now I'm wondering if there is any other way to refer to the "first" class instead of writing `this`. I'm just practicing for my school and I'm a bit curious, not really trying to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class.

In your case it is referring to the current instance of class, where you are checking instance of current class (i.e instance of class `first`) contains log value as "yes" or not.

Answer (score -1):

The **this** pointer represents the current instance of a class or struct.

So the function in class first "something" is as same as below.

```
public bool something(second obj)
{
    if (log == "yes")
        return true;          
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: In C# objects usually don't have access to their address and don't have pointers that point to an address (except when you mark your code as unsafe), but rather use references which reference objects. Technically, these references may be realized via pointers to addresses, but I don't think the specification requires this.